# Multiple TableViews in One UIView Swift - How to show both

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I'm having difficult showing both tableviews in my UIView.

It will only show the second table if I hide the first.

Any help? I need to get it to show both tables, one below the other. It only works individually when hiding the other :(

```
class AccountsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

//MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableview1: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableview2: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Set the table background as the image
    tableview1.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "splasnowords-1.png"))
    tableview2.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "splasnowords-1.png"))

    //Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


    //Calculate the latest totalstandings
    BudgetDataModel.calculateTotalStandings()
    totalLabel.text = ("Total Current Standings = £\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number: BudgetDataModel.total))")

    self.tableview1.delegate = self
    self.tableview2.delegate = self
    self.tableview1.dataSource = self
    self.tableview2.dataSource = self

    self.tableview2.isHidden = false
    self.tableview1.isHidden = true

   // self.tableview.reloadData()
 //   self.tableview2.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    tableview1.reloadData()
    tableview2.reloadData()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
/*
   if (tableView == self.tableview){
    return 1
        //BudgetDataModel.budgets.count
    }
    else if tableView == self.tableview2{
        return 1
            //SavingsDataModel.savings.count
    }
   else{
    return 2
    }*/


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
    //reload data?
    if (tableView == self.tableview1){
    return "Budgets"
    }
    else{
        return "Savings"
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var rowCount = 0
    if (tableView == self.tableview1) {
        rowCount = BudgetDataModel.budgets.count
    }
    if (tableView == self.tableview2) {
        rowCount = SavingsDataModel.savings.count
    }
    return rowCount


    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   //Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.

    if (tableView == self.tableview1){
        let cellIdentifier = "AccountsTableViewCell"
        let cell = self.tableview1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AccountsTableViewCell

        let budget = BudgetDataModel.budgets[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        cell.nameLabel.text = budget.name
        cell.amountLabel.text = ("£\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number: budget.amount))")
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
        return cell
    }
        //Doesn't go into this if statement below
    else {
    //(tableView == self.tableview2)
        let cellIdentifier2 = "SavingsTableViewCell"
        let cell = self.tableview2.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier2, for: indexPath) as! SavingsTableViewCell

        let saving = SavingsDataModel.savings[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        cell.savingsnameLabel.text = saving.savingname
        cell.savingsamountLabel.text = ("£\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number: saving.savingamount))")
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
        return cell
     }
    //return cell
}
   /* else { preconditionFailure ("unexpected cell type") }
}*/


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        if (tableView == self.tableview1){
            // Delete the row from the data source
            BudgetDataModel.budgets.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            BudgetDataModel.saveBudgets()
            BudgetDataModel.calculateTotalStandings()
            totalLabel.text = ("Total Current Standings = £\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number:BudgetDataModel.total))")
           // self.tableview.reloadData()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }
        else if (tableView == self.tableview2){
            // Delete the row from the data source
            SavingsDataModel.savings.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            SavingsDataModel.saveSavings()
            //implement   BudgetDataModel.calculateTotalStandings()
            //implement   totalLabel.text = ("Total Current Standings = £\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number:BudgetDataModel.total))")
            //self.tableview2.reloadData()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}



// Override to support rearranging the table view.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

}


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/



// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail"{
        let budgetDetailViewController = segue.destination as! BudgetViewController
        //Get the cell that generated this segue.
        if let selectedBudgetCell = sender as? AccountsTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableview1.indexPath(for: selectedBudgetCell)!
            let selectedBudget = BudgetDataModel.budgets[indexPath.row]
            budgetDetailViewController.budget = selectedBudget
        }
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "AddItem"{
        //self.tableview.reloadData()
        print("Adding new budget.")
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "ShowSavings"{
            let savingDetailViewController = segue.destination as! SavingsViewController
            //Get the cell that generated this segue.
            if let selectedSavingsCell = sender as? SavingsTableViewCell {
                let indexPath = tableview2.indexPath(for: selectedSavingsCell)!
                let selectedSavings = SavingsDataModel.savings[indexPath.row]
                savingDetailViewController.saving = selectedSavings
            }
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "AddSaving"{
        //self.tableview2.reloadData()
        print ("Adding new saving.")
    }
}

//MARK: Actions

@IBAction func unwindToBudgetList(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? BudgetViewController, let budget = sourceViewController.budget {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableview1.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            //Update an existing budget.
            BudgetDataModel.budgets[selectedIndexPath.row] = budget
            self.tableview1.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
        }
        else{
                //Add a new budget
                let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row:BudgetDataModel.budgets.count, section: 0)
                BudgetDataModel.budgets.append(budget)
                self.tableview1.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .bottom)
            }
        //Save the budgets.
        BudgetDataModel.saveBudgets()
        BudgetDataModel.calculateTotalStandings()
        totalLabel.text = ("Total Current Standings = £\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number: BudgetDataModel.total))")

    }
}

@IBAction func unwindtoSavingsList(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? SavingsViewController, let savings = sourceViewController.saving {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableview2.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            //Update an existing budget.
            SavingsDataModel.savings[selectedIndexPath.row] = savings
            self.tableview2.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
        }
        else{
            //Add a new saving
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row:SavingsDataModel.savings.count, section: 0)
            SavingsDataModel.savings.append(savings)
            self.tableview2.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .bottom)
        }
        //Save the budgets.
        SavingsDataModel.saveSavings()
        //implement    SavingsDataModel.calculateTotalStandings()
        //    totalLabel.text = ("Total Current Standings = £\(BudgetDataModel.returnTrueValue(number: BudgetDataModel.total))")

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it will only show the second table"? Do you mean the first table takes up the full screen? Do you mean the size of the first table is correct, but the second table is missing? Do you mean both tables are showing, but only the first is filled with data?

Comment: @DongMag, to clarify, I meant the size of the first table is correct, but the second table is missing.

Comment: Is it being "pushed out of view" by bad constraints maybe? Have you tried using Debug View Hierarchy to see if the table exists, and if so to check its frame / location?

Comment: @DonMag I originally thought bad constraints, so put it all into a stack view, and found that it wasn't the issue. Checked in Debug View Hierarchy and can see the UITableView for my second tableview is in the focused list, however when I select it, I can't see anything.

Comment: When you're in Debug View Hierarchy, you can select Object or Size Inspector in the Utilities pane on the right. When you have the second table selected in the list, check the details on those two panes. It will show frame bounds, position, constraints, etc, etc, etc... maybe do a screen cap if nothing looks obvious?

Comment: @DonMag,Thanks, so what i've tried is to take it out of the stack view after looking at your suggestions and seen that it now shows both tables, however horribly they look, they are now present and correct. Just need to somehow sort the constraints so that one doesn't remove the other again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in my case it was due to my constraints as I had put them into a stack view but with the stack view not set to distribute correctly. So I needed to amend that setting in the storyboard. Then both were present and correct as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise adding them separate using ContainerViews like so:

[image]

This will make it a lot easier to keep code in their separate ViewControllers and will keep your application accessible.

Comment: curious, are there any tutorials that teach you how to connect a UIView to a separate controller? I've never seen this before, very interesting!

Comment: @Jay I just ctrl dragged from the Container View to the Table View Controller, nothing special. This is a good Swift 3 tutorial I used to set up Container Views with dynamic contents: https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/

Answer (score 2):

Suggest use a standard VC not a TVC and 2 tableviews in your view.  Connect each to the VC as an outlet.  Add protocols UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource to your VC.  Then, in IB, control drag from each tableview to the leftmost icon in the VC header and connect up Delegate and DataSource.  Lastly, select each TableView and give it a Tag value so you can differentiate between them in the Tableview methods.

Comment: This worked for me.  Wish there was a better way though.